# Make a form of check boxes containing a database elements?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a column Questions in my table oeQuestions. I want to output each question with a checkbox to the left of it and at the end of them being outputted someone could select which ones they wanted and on submit button the next page will pop up with only the selected questions. I can finally print each question with a checkbox but i need help dynamically changing the values for each as well (my submit button is not shown) any help would be great.

```
 <div style="font-family: kodakku; font-size:25px; font-weight:bold;">
     <?php 
     $sql = " SELECT Question FROM multQuestions ";
     $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);

     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
       {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
             echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar[]" value="Option One">' . $row["Question"]." <br />";
            }
       }
  ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: you're dumping out a bunch of `Option One` values, for every record you fetch. that value should be dynamic as well, one per record you fetch.

Comment: @MarcB its the answer. Not the comment :3

Comment: Thats my problem I need help doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @MarcB was saying in his comment is that you need a unique identifier as the value.

This means you have to add it to your select:

```
 <div style="font-family: kodakku; font-size:25px; font-weight:bold;">
     <?php 
     $sql = " SELECT ID, Question FROM multQuestions ";
     $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
```

(Note, I used `ID`... you DO have a unique ID on your multQuestions table, right?)

And then use it as the value:

```
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
       {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
             echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar[]" value="'.$row["ID"].'">' . $row["Question"]." <br />";
            }
       }
  ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: i do have an ID column yes but how would i grab them fr then next page?

Comment: couldnt i use # istead of id if i didnt anyway?

Comment: On the next page you would query `WHERE ID IN( [the list of IDs] )`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "use #"?

Comment: theres an automatic column to the left of ID the has # and it is the same increments as ID, only reason i ask is because if i delete a question the ID will disappear with it rather then change the ID for  all questions down one. and on the next page i need to grab it with post from submit

Answer (score 1):

Digital Chris is correct. You need a way to increment your checkbox ids to uniquely identify them currently they will all have the same value.
This becomes especially important if you then want to handle them as individual checkboxes.

Comment: i understand that its been said twice, its a matter of handling them individually my problem

Comment: He has given you a solution. Have a column in you database that increments or just asign the value you want. The then echo it as your input id. They will then have different ids. Then just document.getElementByID('your input Id') to handle it. He has used value in his example but it's all the same. Just grab the element by its value